# Installing updated App React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to install the app which I am developing. When I use the command `react-native run-android` the app builds and installs successfully. It does how ever skip `:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED`. When I open the app, it is an outdated version. How do I install the latest version of my app?

**EDIT 1**

The updated version of the app runs on our AVD.
Trying `npm install -g` did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you need to have the adb installed and working. In order to do this, you need to edit your system variables. You need to add the path to your adb which is installed with your android api.

The default path for the adb is: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

This needs to be appended to the path variable for your username. to edit the environment variables you need to:

Open your start menu,
Type in environment variables and press enter,
Click edit system variables,
Select the path variable and click edit,
Add the path to the adb to the end of the list,
Save your settings and restart cmd,
type echo %PATH%. You should see your add path,
run react-native run-android from your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g
```

or

```
yarn upgrade
```

Comment: It still installed an outdated version of my app